# Wordpress Gravity Form Plugin [HELP]

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a form at my website where the user can request for information, but there's a catch. Inside the form I have a checkbox and when the user selects it, the email must to be sent to another place. (See the screenshots)

[image]

[image]

What's happening is: Gravity form sends both emails when both rules match, but I only wanna send one email based on the priority.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the routing will take into account AND conditions for the individual rules.

You can however, use the following filter to do further modifications to the e-mail before it is being sent:

```
add_filter("gform_notification", "my_custom_function", 10, 3);
```

Or, for a specific form (i.e. id = 42):

```
add_filter("gform_notification_42", "my_custom_function", 10, 3);
```

Source: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_notification

*Update*

An example of accessing the fields would look like this:

```
add_filter('gform_notification_42', 'updateNotificationForForm42', 10, 3);
function updateNotificationForForm42( $notification, $form, $entry ) {
    $fields = $form['fields'];
    foreach( $fields as $field ) {
        // Here you need to provide the field with some kind of identifying mark (e.g., Admin Label).  
        // Below assumes the field you're interested in has an admin label of 'Test Me'
        if( $field['adminLabel'] == 'Test Me' ) {
            $fieldValue = rgpost("input_{$field['id']}");
        }
    }
}
```

The Gravity Forms [developer docs](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Developer_Docs) have a lot of examples of how to customize via actions/filters.

See Also: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Fields

Comment: Thanks for that! How can I access the values of the fields? Give me an example here.